# C++ multiple random numbers adding up to equal a certain number

Tags: c++, loops, random

Having a little trouble figuring this one out, I have a bunch of int variables which are generating random numbers from 1-9. I need them to generate the correct numbers to equal to a certain number, for example 30.

```
int numone = rand()%10;
int numtwo = rand()%10;
int numthree = rand()%10;
int numfour = rand()%10;
int finalsum;

do{
finalsum = numone + numtwo + numthree + numfour;
}while(finalsum !=30);
```

I am not sure if I am going about this the right way but when I try to compile the above code, I don't even get a number and sometimes I get a "Time limit exceeded" error, perhaps it is taking too long. Is there another way I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, i hope you realize that in your do while loop, you are not actually changing the values of the random numbers.What you are doing is basically checking the same condition of `finalsum = numone + numtwo + numthree + numfour;` infinitely if it does not equal 30.What you should do is:

```
int numone,numtwo,numthree,numfour,finalsum;
do{
numone=rand()%10;
numtwo=rand()%10;
numthree=rand()%10;
numfour=rand()%10;
finalsum = numone + numtwo + numthree + numfour;
}while(finalsum !=30);
```

Answer (score 2):

Move the `rand()` into the while loop, or you'll generate random numbers only once, and get  stucked in while loop.

```
do{
int numone = rand()%10;
int numtwo = rand()%10;
int numthree = rand()%10;
int numfour = rand()%10;
int finalsum;
finalsum = numone + numtwo + numthree + numfour;
}while(finalsum !=30);
```

Answer (score 0):

The chance that you get '30' for a result is pretty small. You also don't get a random number from 1 to 9, you get them from 0 to 9.

Try this instead:

```
int numone,numtwo,numthree,numfour, finalsum;
do
{
   do
   {
     numone = 1+rand()%9;
     numtwo = 1+rand()%9;
   } while (numone+numtwo < 12);
   numthree = 1+rand()%9;
} while (numone+numtwo+numthree < 21);
numfour = 30-(numone+numtwo+numthree);
// for clarity
finalsum = numone + numtwo + numthree + numfour;
```

(Edit) After some lateral thinking: `numthree` needs to be between `30-1-(numone+numtwo)` and `30-9-(numone+numtwo)` -- perhaps there is room for a small further optimization there.

(Further edit) After the deliberations below I actually *tested* it, and indeed, this works per requirement:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

int main (void)
{
  int numone,numtwo,numthree,numfour, finalsum;
  int i;

  srand(time(NULL));

  for (i=0; i<100; i++)
  {
    numone = 3+rand()%7;
    if (numone == 3)
      numtwo = 9;
    else
      numtwo = 12-numone+rand()%(7-(9-numone));
    if (numone + numtwo == 12)
      numthree = 9;
    else
      numthree = 21-(numone+numtwo)+rand()%(6-(18-(numone+numtwo)));
    numfour = 30 - (numone + numtwo + numthree);

    finalsum = numone + numtwo + numthree + numfour;
    printf ("%d + %d + %d + %d = %d\n", numone, numtwo, numthree, numfour, finalsum);
  }
}
```

Comment: Additional: Since the *sum* of `n1+n2` must be 12..18 -- it needs to be at least 12, where n3 and n4 are both `9`, and it cannot be higher than 9+9 -- you can also calculate `n2` a bit smarter. ..Hmm.. a bit more difficult than I expected :)

Comment: Also additional: your range of 1..9 for all numbers *cannot work*! As soon as *any* of your numbers is less than 3, you can't reach the target value '30' anymore. So a better random would be `3+rand()%7`.

Comment: Okay. If `3 <= n1,n2 <= 9` and `12 <= n1+n2 <= 18` then n2 needs to be at least `12-n1`. So `n2=12-n1+rand()%(6-(9-n1))`. A modulus 0 is invalid, so first test if `n1==3`, and if so `n2=9`. (Going to lie down now for a bit.)

Comment: We're getting there: at this point, `n1+n2` are between 12..18. For the last number `n4` to be 1..9 (actually 3..9), `n1+n2+n3` needs to be 21..27 (you can't make 28 or 29). As we know `n1+n2` at this point, you can say `n3=21-(n1+n2)+rand()%(6-(18-(n1+n2)))`, and again, first test `n1+n2==12` because then `n3=9`. Fortunately, `n4` is easy to calculate!

Comment: Ah wait. The `6-..` I used in `n2` and `n3` probably needs to be `7-..` instead. I think it's time to actually *try* this cuz this far I've only been applying logic.