# Array of random numbers with sum in given range?

Tags: c, algorithm, random

In C, how do I get an array of *n* numbers (each 0x00-0xFF in my case), of which the sum is within a given range `0..k`?

The *almost* duplicate [C++ multiple random numbers adding up to equal a certain number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18690975/2564301) targets a specific sum, but in my case the sum can be anything between `0..k`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify what is the desired distribution of the random numbers.

If there are no further requirements, I would suggest one of the following:

---

(1)

- pick random number *a[1]* in interval *0 .. k*
- pick random number *a[2]* in interval *0 .. k-a[1]*
- pick random number *a[3]* in interval *0 .. k-a[1]-a[2]*
- ...
- pick random number *a[n]* in interval *0 .. k-a[1]-a[2]-...-a[n-1]*

If you have upper limit *m* on the range of the random number, use *min(k-a[1]-... m)* as upper bound of the interval.

Disadvantages: you will get a lot of small numbers and just a few big ones.

---

(2)

- pick *n* random numbers *a[1], .., a[n]* in interval *0 .. m*, *m* being the upper limit
- *s = a[1]+a[2]+...+a[n]*
- multiply each *a[i]* by *k/s* (if integers are required, round down)

Disadvantages: It is unlikely to get large numbers this way. If integers are required, there will likely be a gap between the sum of numbers and *k* due to rounding error.

---

I think you get "nicer" numbers with option (2) but as stated above, it depends on the requirements.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `k` is less than `255 * n` one solution is to assign `k / n` to every element of the array, then randomly subtract a value to the array elements.

```
// for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) array[i] = k / n;
// for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) array[i] -= randbetween(0, array[i]);
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) array[i] = randbetween(0, k / n);
```

This has an expected sum of `k / 2`. By tweaking the `randbetween()` function you can change the probability of the resulting array sum.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to create one number within range `[0, 255]`.

It is easy to identify if `k > 255*n` or `k < 0` there is no solution.

If `0 <= k <= 255*n`, the solution exists. Here we only talk about `n > 1` condition.

You have created `n-1` random numbers, and sum of the `n-1` numbers is `s1`, suppose the nth number is `x`. So `s1 + x = k`, and x should be `[0, 255]`. ***If the `n-1` numbers are all within range `[0, a]`, then `(n-1)*a + 255 >= k`***, we get `a >= (k-255)/(n-1)`.

If `k > 255`, just let `a = (k-255)/(n-1)`. It means `s1` is `[0, k-255]`. Then the nth number `x` can be any random number within `[0, 255]`.
So the solution is arbitrary select `n-1` numbers each within `[0, (k-255)/(n-1)]` (you know `(k-255)/(n-1) <= 255`, thus it satisfied your condition), and select one random number within `[0, 255]`.

If `k <= 255`, arbitrary select `n` numbers each within `[0, k/n]` (you know `k/n` is within [0, 255]).

Comment: Problem with this approach is when `-s1 < 0` and/or `k - s1 > 255`.

Comment: Looks like it works now ... but too much math for this early in the morning :)